Apply several css transforms with transition after each other
I try to have an interactive animation of two (later more) linked rotation tables, the element in the intersection is supposed to be affected by either element. Allowing all 3 blocks to be ordered in any configuration.
The swapping of two elements is straightforward enough with a rotation trnasformation. The issue is the repeated application of the transformation. I get that my problem is that the coordinates of the react element are not updated after the rotation. however changing them would trigger another transition.
So I think what I am asking is: how do I trigger after the transition then turning of of transition, then update the coordinates of the element  and then turn on transitions again. For keeping the turned over state I was think of maybe using a 3d transform matrix. For the movement the matrix is out of the question as it just translates the object along the line.
The rectangle object is a placeholder for images to be added at a later point in time.
This is how far I got with he turtables, click on the circle border to turn.


    function isRectangleInsideCircle(rect, circle) {
        // Get circle center and radius
        const cx = parseFloat(circle.getAttribute('cx'));
        const cy = parseFloat(circle.getAttribute('cy'));
        const r = parseFloat(circle.getAttribute('r'));

        // Calculate the center of the rectangle
        const rectX = parseFloat(rect.getAttribute('x'));
        const rectY = parseFloat(rect.getAttribute('y'));
        const rectWidth = parseFloat(rect.getAttribute('width'));
        const rectHeight = parseFloat(rect.getAttribute('height'));

        // Transform the coordinates if necessary
        const transform = rect.getAttribute('transform');
        let transformedX = rectX;
        let transformedY = rectY;
        if (transform) {
            const scaleMatch = /scale\(-1,1\)/.exec(transform);
            if (scaleMatch) {
                transformedX = -rectX - rectWidth;
            }
        }

        const rectCenterX = transformedX + rectWidth / 2;
        const rectCenterY = rectY + rectHeight / 2;

        // Check if the distance from the rectangle center to the circle center is within the radius
        const distance = Math.sqrt((rectCenterX - cx) ** 2 + (rectCenterY - cy) ** 2);

        return distance <= r;
    }

    function rotateElement(circleId) {
        const circle = document.getElementById(circleId);

        // Get the center coordinates of the circle
        const cx = parseFloat(circle.getAttribute('cx'));
        const cy = parseFloat(circle.getAttribute('cy'));

        // Get all rectangles
        const rectangles = document.querySelectorAll('rect.rotatable');

        // Calculate the current rotation angle (default 0 if not set)
        let currentRotation = circle.getAttribute('data-rotation') || 0;
        currentRotation = parseInt(currentRotation);

        // Increase the angle by 180 degrees
        currentRotation += 180;

        // Apply rotation to the circle around its center
        circle.style.transform = `rotate(${currentRotation}deg)`;
        circle.style.transformOrigin = `${cx}px ${cy}px`;

        // Apply rotation to each rectangle that is inside the circle
        rectangles.forEach(rect => {
            if (isRectangleInsideCircle(rect, circle)) {
                const originalTransform = rect.getAttribute('transform') || '';
                rect.style.transformOrigin = `${cx}px ${cy}px`;
                rect.style.transform = `rotate(${currentRotation}deg) ${originalTransform}`;
                
            }
        });

        // Store the new rotation angle in the circle's data-rotation attribute
        circle.setAttribute('data-rotation', currentRotation);
    }

    // Attach the onclick event to each rotatable circle
    document.querySelectorAll('circle.rotatable').forEach(circle => {
        circle.onclick = function() {
            rotateElement(this.id);
        };
    });
      svg {
            width: 600px;
            height: 600px;
        }
        .rotatable {
            transition: transform 2s linear;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>

<svg viewBox="0 0 184 184" id="svg-root">
 <defs>
    <linearGradient id="redgradient" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="gold" />
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="red" />
    </linearGradient>
    
        <linearGradient id="bluegradient" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="gold" />
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="blue" />
    </linearGradient>
    
       <linearGradient id="greengradient" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="gold" />
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="green" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <circle
     cx="64"
     cy="92"
     r="59"
     fill="none"
     opacity="0.4"
     stroke="#000000"
     stroke-width="4"
     class="rotatable"
     id="smallring1" />
  <rect
     x="21.000002"
     y="78"
     width="27"
     height="27"
     fill=url("#redgradient")
     opacity="0.4"
     class="rotatable"
     id="red1" />
     
     
  <circle
     cx="123"
     cy="92"
     r="59"
     fill="none"
     opacity="0.4"
     stroke="#000000"
     stroke-width="4"
     class="rotatable"
     id="smallring2" />
  <rect
     x="146"
     y="78"
     width="27"
     height="28"
      fill=url("#bluegradient")
     opacity="0.4"
     class="rotatable"
     id="blue1" />
  <rect
     id="green"
     x="76"
     y="78"
     width="27"
     height="28"
       fill=url("#greengradient")
     opacity="0.4"
     class="rotatable" />
</svg>



</body>
</html>



